# Should we have one tag per Anime/Manga series?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've seen we have a tag for [bleach](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bleach), [naruto](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto), [dragonball-z](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonball-z), etc.  Should that be what we do going forward for every series?  Have a [neon-genesis-evangelion](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neon-genesis-evangelion) tag? A [fullmetal-alchemist](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fullmetal-alchemist) tag? Or will that give us way too many tags, since there are quite a few different series out there?  Is there some threshold of popularity you need to merit a tag for a given series?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. A series tag is a vital part of a question on a site about literature, gaming, et cetera, and are a great example of the type of tags a site should have.

- **Represent an area of expertise**: It's possible for users to be an expert in a specific series, having an in-depth knowledge of it's world and characters.
- **Useful as a Filter**: Ideally our site will have a large volume of questions. With this in mind being able to easily sort by series is essential to make finding relevant questions easy and painless. Can you imagine trying to track down a question for a specific series if we didn't have series tags? Not only would it a painful experience, it would be enough for people to not want to use the site (I wouldn't. Searching would be impossible)
- **A Tag People will Follow**: Users will always be willing to follow (favourite) a series tag, and are likely to be among the top followed tags on the site. Due to this, they should exist.
- **A Tag People Will Want to Ignore**: If I don't read a series, then I won't care about any of it's questions aside from moderation purposes. Due to this I should be able to ignore any questions from this tag so they don't clog up on my front page. This is also very useful for **spoilers.** If I'm currently in the process of watching a series which I'm not up to date on I won't want to stumble across spoilers when I visit the front page of the site. The ability to ignore and hide tags is ideal for solving this problem.

Answer (score 6):

Yes

There's no other way to identify which Anime is applicable to the question other than in the question title. This can get unwieldy - especially for longer titles.

---

And also for questions that apply to multiple Anime series such as: "To Aru Majutsu no Index" and "To Aru Kagaku no Railgun".

It's better to just apply both tags instead of trying to squeeze them into the title.

Comment: Especially if the Japanese title is used: *Yamato Nadeshiko Shichi na Henge!* is considerably longer than *Perfect Girl Evolution!*

Comment: Specifically, I'd say one tag per franchise is what we want.

Comment: @Xeo Actually, we might need two, see [the edit at the bottom of my post.](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/28/60)

Comment: 'There's no other way to identify which Anime is applicable to the question other than in the question title.' --> Genre? I'm not saying it's a good way, but I'd argue it's a way. Of course it's not what they do in scifi or movies se.

Answer (score 4):

I think we should take a cue from [Science Fiction and Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com) here; for a distinct work, have a tag for the work.  It doesn't matter if there's only *one* question for the tag, if it's about a legitimate on topic work, then the tag should exist for searchability as well as future questions.

If the work is part of a series, then a tag for the series can exist as well.

An example of would be [macross](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macross) as well as [macross-plus](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macross-plus).

Perhaps, for series, we would want to do something like [macross-series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macross-series) and then have [macross](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macross) for the original and then [macross-plus](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macross-plus).

If this approach is taken, then we should request that [the script that deletes tags that have a low number of posts on them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127700/140951) be disabled for this site.

---

Thinking about this more, we might actually need *more* than one tag per series.  Given that each series has commonly accepted Japanese *and* English titles, we'll probably need to be able to tag the question with both of them.

I don't know that synonyms are a good thing here, because it might cause flame wars over what the preference site-wide should be (and we certainly don't *not* have the space for two tags for a series on the question).

Comment: I'll start new meta post about your edit.

Comment: Looks like Xeo beat me to it.

Comment: @Mysticial Thieves!  The lot of you!

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you consider *not* just holing yourselves into the "one tag per anime/manga" mindset for a number of reasons we learned the hard way in Gaming:

- **Tag length limit.** You'd be surprised how often this comes up. Want to talk about "Assassin's Creed 3: Liberation"? "assassins-creed-3-liberation" is way too long, "assassins-creed-liberation" is 26 characters...
- **Title localization.** Are you going to use "death-note" or "デスノート"? You can accept both, but you need to pick the one that goes in the titlebar — and that's very important Google-wise. So you might decide "okay, let's go with the English title whenever possible because the site is in English." What about animes that lack an *official* title in English, then?
- **Lack of character support.** Remember what I said about accepting "デスノート" as a tag or at least a tag synonym? Yeah, you can't do that. Yet. UTF-8 support in tags is currently only being tried on [Japanese.SE](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/966/2908), afaik. Sure, it's easy to see a request for enabling this feature here too granted, but you should still be aware that it comes to the price of stability.
- **[untagged](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).** A work that doesn't get two questions asked about it in the same six months gets retroactively changed into [untagged](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged). If you rely solely on tags to know what anime/manga you're talking about, that... is very bad news. Thanks to Patents.SE and much pressure, Arqade managed to disable this process at the cost of, well, automatically pruning tags that do deserve pruning. That's another "special needs" request you might want to look into, at any rate.

Additionally there are a few ways that would make this even worse for Anime.SE than it is for Arqade:

- **Questions that are not about a single manga are on-topic.** On Arqade questions about games in general are regarded as "game design questions" more appropriate for GameDev. This is not true here and there's already plenty of questions about anime design, reading and production in general. What I've found is that "one tag per game" tends to cannibalize all other forms of tagging (consider for example [plot-disconnect](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-disconnect), which one could easily consider a poisonous meta-tag that isn't useful as a filter or as an area of experitse.) The thought process that kicks in eventually is that "single work tags" are the superior kind of tag and everything else is useless. You clearly don't want this.
- **Even when it comes to "single work per tag," you still need to distinguish between anime and manga versions.** Except when you don't. Arqade approaches this by using (for example) "mass-effect-series" when asking questions about all Mass Effect canon (as opposed to "mass-effect" which is just about the first game), but such an approach is less likely to work well here. Consider "one-note": is it about the manga, the anime, both?

It is silly to say "don't make tags for single anime/mangas" (you *will* want tags for all major works - but where do you draw the line?), but going the opposite side and making a tag for *all* single animes or mangas brings about a lot of challenges, most of which aren't actually fun or rewarding to overcome. You end up wasting time on how to tag "Asaoka High School Baseball Club Diary: Over Fence", cursing about [untagged](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) and generally not spending time actually doing questions and answers.

This is still day one and you still have a chance to break from the tyranny of "one game per tag." I suggest you consider it, starting perhaps by being precise in either the question title or body about what your question is actually about.

Comment: On Unicode support in tags, Russian and Japanese, but we're actually soon testing on a couple other language sites as well. It's looking pretty positive though.

Comment: Very valuable point of view: I'm concerned about having many tag for the same series and for the "untagged" issue. On the other hand, the "area of expertise" Wipqozn is talking about is appealing to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's perfectly acceptable. There're language specific tags over on Stack Overflow, one for each language, and sometimes even more ([php](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php) [php4](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php4) [php5](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php5) etc).

On Arqade, there's a tag for each game. So I disagree with you. Anime/Manga specific tags should be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I'm not sure if there is a good justification for any other kind of tag, at the moment.

The first tag tends to dominate SEO considerations (since it is prepended to the page title), and should generally match the series name.