# Is it alright to ask questions about unlocalized anime/manga?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Localization can take some time to complete, but some people are eager to discuss current ongoing series (E.g. Rebuild of Evangelion) from Japan.

Can we ask question about (past, current, and future) unlocalized anime and manga series?

Should we only allow series that have "unofficial" fan translations?

How should we tag them once they have been officially localized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any reason not to allow asking about it, and some questions already have.

However, as a practical matter, fansubs are illegal in most parts of the world. Although this hasn't been tested in court to the best of my knowledge, we're better safe than sorry when it comes to things like that. As such, questions about specific fan translations probably shouldn't be allowed. I think SE policy also requires that we don't advocate or discuss things which are illegal to some degree.

I also don't see any reason to restrict to only those shows that have been translated. Some people here speak Japanese, and anime in its most natural form is in Japanese, so there's no problem asking about shows that haven't yet been translated.

As for tagging, that has a separate meta question here: [Should we have one tag per Anime/Manga series?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/should-we-have-one-tag-per-anime-manga-series). To keep things easy to follow I'd advise you to pose that question there. Note that the SE software does (to the best of my knowledge) support merging tags.

Comment: So, I could ask about the translation nuance *so long as* I didn't reference that the scans/subs were fanmade? Bleach scans occasionally have this problem, for example.